# Bulk list of URLs - delete query (fragment) part only

Tags: bash

I have a large list of URLs (one per line) in a test file, and I want to remove in the whole list the query parts in the URL (if there). The same method should apply in another list with the fragment part. The list looks like:

```
http://test0.com/a.exe
http://test1.com/a.exe?p=123
http://test2.com/a.exe#fragment
http://test3.com/a.exe?p=123#fragment
http://test3.com/a.exe#fragment?p=123
```

In case of removing the query part, the list should look after it like:

```
http://test0.com/a.exe
http://test1.com/a.exe
http://test2.com/a.exe#fragment
http://test3.com/a.exe#fragment
http://test3.com/a.exe#fragment
```

In case of removing the fragment part:

```
http://test0.com/a.exe
http://test1.com/a.exe?p=123
http://test2.com/a.exe
http://test3.com/a.exe?p=123
http://test3.com/a.exe?p=123
```

Because the lists have thousands of entries, it should NOT be done line by line in a loop. I need something which can be used in a pipe too and should use the normal Unix toolset.

I am struggeling with awk, cut ... with such a function (because its not a simple delimeter case):

```
list function 1:
delete in every line the part from '?' to ( end-of-line or '#')

list function 2:
delete in every line the part from '#' to ( end-of-line or '?')
```

Before I write now a small C program, I like to ask, if it can be done easier?

Many thanks in advance!

Ralf

Answer (score 1):

Using any sed:

```
$ sed 's/?[^#?]*//' file
http://test0.com/a.exe
http://test1.com/a.exe
http://test2.com/a.exe#fragment
http://test3.com/a.exe#fragment
http://test3.com/a.exe#fragment

$ sed 's/#[^#?]*//' file
http://test0.com/a.exe
http://test1.com/a.exe?p=123
http://test2.com/a.exe
http://test3.com/a.exe?p=123
http://test3.com/a.exe?p=123
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this :

```bash
sed -E 's/\?[^#]+//' file.txt
```

Comment: Man thanks, that worked fine, with such constructs I was struggeling badly because of a lack of knowledge and expierence ....
sed -E "s/\?[^\?]+//" url.list and  sed -E "s/\#[^\?]+//" url.list works ver good for my purpose.
Many thanks !!!

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton for your feedback, I've edited my answer